# Regarding Max function in MDX

Tags: sql, ssas, max, mdx

I have a fact table with structure: (objectid, fromLoc, toLoc, duration).

I need the equivalent MDX for the following SQL:

```
select fromLoc, toLoc, max(duration) from fact group by fromLoc, toLoc;
```

I tried with the following MDX but it's showing wrong results. It's showing sum(duration) instead of showing max value for each grouping:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[MaxValue] AS
  max([Measures].[Duration]) 
 select FromLoc.members on axis(1),
toLoc.members  on axis(0)
from [cube1]
where [Measures].[MaxValue]
```

Please help me by providing the correct MDX which can answer the queries like the above SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You have have to use the [max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145601.aspx) function like this:

```
max(the set of your objectids, [Measures].[Duration])
```

Comment: I tried with the following and still it shows the sum as result.
    WITH
   MEMBER [Measures].[MaxValue] AS
   max(FromLoc.members, [Measures].[Duration]) 
    select FromLoc.members on axis(1),
    toLoc.members  on axis(0)
    from [cube1]
where [Measures].[MaxValue];

Is there any syntax to find this max with more than one dimension?

Comment: @AhmedTanvir you must put in the first argument the set of your ``objectid``s. I updated my answer

Comment: I also tried with the following:
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[MaxValue] AS
  max(Object.objectid.members, [Measures].[Duration]) 
  select FromLoc.members on axis(1),
  toLoc.members  on axis(0)
  from [cube1]
  where [Measures].[MaxValue]

Still it shows the sum result. It kills my whole day.

Comment: @AhmedTanvir ``Object.objectid.members`` must contains the All member that is why you get sum(duration)

Comment: Objectid is the most lower level granularity for object and it already contain all the member's isn't it? Actually I need among the objects that travel between each fromloc and toloc pair and the max duration taken by among of those objects to go from fromloc and toloc. Thanks for your continuous support!

Comment: @AhmedTanvir Do you see something wrong in the result of this query: ``select NON EMPTY Object.objectid.members on columns, NON EMPTY CrossJoin(FromLoc.members, toLoc.members) on rows from [cube1] where [Measures].[Duration]`` ?

Comment: @Benoti: It took huge time to execute this query as I have huge amount of objects. How this query is relevant for the above question?

Comment: @AhmedTanvir The expression I gave you must return the max value on each row. So if you see on the rows the sum of the durations that would explain what you got with max.